# Number Theory: Binary Quadratic Forms Representations

Tags: number-theory

Find a necessary and sufficient condition for an integer $n$ to be properly
represented by at least one of the two forms

$$x^2 + xy + 4y^2$$
$$ 2x^2 + xy + 2y^2$$

Comment: Use mathjax. Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: No idea whether it helps : $$x^2+xy+4y^2=\frac{(2x+y)^2+15y^2}{4}$$ and $$2x^2+xy+2y^2=\frac{(4x+y)^2+15y^2}{8}$$

Comment: look at what happens mod $15$.